# Bind Results from a Left Join using mysqli

Tags: sql, join, mysqli, bind

I'm recently changing to mysqli and while performing an update on a script, i couldn't manage to use the same SELECT information as i did before. How can I bind_results from a Left Join between 3 tables?

This is the script:

```sql
SELECT actor.id, actor.name, actor.gender, 
       thumbs.id, thumbs.filename, thumbs.actorid
FROM actors, thumbs
LEFT JOIN join_thumbscategory
ON thumbs.id=join_thumbscategory.thumbsid
WHERE join_thumbscategory.categoryid='$id_category'
AND thumbs.actorid=actor.id
ORDER BY actor.name ASC
```

How can I join 3 tables and bind the results? I'm trying to use msqli prepared statements.

Comment: it seems nobody knows what you want to do, neither do i. explain better or show more code.

Comment: Solved the problem i had! Thanks for all the views!
Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Little late on this one, but I believe the answer is that you put a condition for join_thumbscategory in your WHERE clause, which doesn't always work like you'd expect. I'm pretty sure if you move it to your LEFT JOIN...ON clause, it'll work.